# Will a non-linear lower bound on some NP complete problem prove non-linear lower bound on 3SAT?

Tags: reductions, np-complete

A problem $\Pi$ is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete if there is a polynomial time reduction from an $\mathsf{NP}$ complete problem $\Pi^\circ$ to $\Pi$ with polynomial blow up on number of variables and instance size.

What are some examples where the involved polynomial blow up on number of variables is a large degree polynomial (correspondingly giving a large degree polynomial time reduction)?

Reason I am asking is this: suppose someone proves a non-linear lower bound on some NP complete problem, is there a direct way to infer that there is a non-linear lower bound for 3SAT by tracing back reductions?

Related: [Natural candidate against the Isomorphism Conjecture?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/natural-candidate-against-the-isomorphism-conjecture)

Comment: circuit-SAT to formula-SAT $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Could you please write your answer?

Comment: The usual reduction from SAT to 3-SAT may increase the number of variables exponentially, even though the instance size only increases polynomially, and the polynomial has low degree.  This doesn't give a high-degree polynomial-time reduction.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon So there is no way to infer non-linear SAT lower bound, unless instance size is linear in blow up? Is there a natural example of a quadratic instance size increment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you regard as natural, but the deterministic time hierarchy theorem guarantees that either there is an infinite hierarchy of problems in P which require larger and larger degrees of the polynomials bounding the number of steps in any many-one reduction of these problems to SAT, or that P ≠ NP.  See also https://constraints.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/pnp-consequences/

Comment: Of course there are NP-completeness reductions that blow up instance size super-linearly. Since we have not refuted ETH yet, this is true for any reduction for an NP-complete problem with a known $2^{o(n)}$ algorithm. One example is Feedback Arc Set on tournament digraphs, and here are more http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9817/1490.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I like this post of yours very much. If you may, you could post an excellent answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The reduction from circuit-SAT to formula-SAT increases the number of variables

by the number of internal gates, since it is also a reduction to CNF-SAT.

It creates a new variable for each internal gate and creates

$\;\;\;$ one or more clauses asserting the truth of the circuit's output

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;\;\;$ the clauses $\:$ (input or output) , ((not input) or not output) $\:$ for each NOT gate

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;\;\;$ clauses $\:$ (i_0 or i_1 or ... or i_(fanin-1) or not output) , (output or not i_0)

$\;\;\;$ , (output or not i_1) , ... , (output or not i_(fanin-1)) $\:$ for each OR gate

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;\;\;$ clauses $\:$ ((not i_0) or (not i_1) or ... or (not i_(fanin-1)) or output) , (i_0 or not output)

$\;\;\;$ , (i_1 or not output) , ... , (i_(fanin-1) or not output) $\:$ for each AND gate

.
However, that reduction does not blowup instance size.

Comment: Do you know the exact numbers (mathematical details) by which the blow up occurs?

Comment: The exact numbers are "the number of internal gates". $\:$ What do you men by "mathematical details"? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: number of gates is what function of variables? is it quadratic?

Comment: If [fanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC0) is at most 2 then number of internal gates is at least [number of variables minus 2]. $\:$ Otherwise, number of gates is completely independent of number of variables. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: This is just a linear blow up then.

Comment: "This is just a linear blow up" of instance size, but an exponential blow up "on number of variables". $\;$

Comment: Could you please provide the explicit reduction?

Comment: (In fact, I'm suddenly far from confident that it will only increase instance size linearly.) $\;$